# How do i save a arraylist in android?

Tags: android, serialization, arraylist

I am trying to store an `ArrayList` in `onstop()` and recover them by calling `getlist()` on startup but it doesn't seem to work: nothing gets recovered and not sure if its even storing is my code correct?

```
public class Schedule extends Activity {
Context context = this;
ArrayList<appointment> listoffappointments = new ArrayList<appointment>();
ArrayList<appointment> myArray;
ArrayList<Calendar> listofcalenders = new ArrayList<Calendar>();
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_appointments);
instance =this;
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myDataListListView) ;     
    refresh();
}

   public void refresh()
    {

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(instance,R.layout.mylist, listoffappointments) ;

        listView.setAdapter(adapter) ;
    }


@overide
protected void onResume() {

    FileInputStream input = null;
    ObjectInputStream inputob = null;
    try {
        input = openFileInput("app.ser");
        inputob = new ObjectInputStream(input);
         myArray = (ArrayList<appointment>) inputob.readObject(); 




 // listoffappointments.addAll(myArray);
 THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP I WANT THE INITIAL LIST LISTOFFAPPOINTMENTS TO HAVE ALL THE ELEMENTS OF myArray when i print each element in myArray onclose the elements i add are present but when i do listoffappointments.addall(myArray); i get a null pointerexception this is why i have the code commented


        inputob.close();
        input.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    super.onResume();
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {



    try {
        FileOutputStream file  =openFileOutput("app.ser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(file);
        oos.writeObject(listoffappointments);
        oos.close();
        file.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(appointment b : myArray)
    {
        System.out.println(b.gettext());
    }


    super.onStop();
}
```

please take a look at the comment in my code for onresume()

Comment: Your logcat is definitely worth a read. The EOFException should be your main focus :p

Comment: I'd recommend looking into ORMLite. It works quite well for the storage of collections of objects. http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Use-With-Android

Comment: in my getlist method i do  ArrayList<appointment> myArray = (ArrayList<appointment>) inputob.readObject(); inputob.readObject(); is that the cause of my error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you should add a `serialVersionUID` to your `Serializable` object. This is good practice for future compatibility.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1l;
```

Second, you probably want to capitalize you object name (`Appointment`); that's the convention.

Third, you should read/write your object from/to your app's file directory. You get that directory using `Context.getFilesDir()`. Here's an example of what the code might look like:

```
private List<Appointment> mAppointments = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
private List<Appointment> mListOfAppointments = new ArrayList<Appointment>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mFile = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir(), "MyFile.ser");

}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(mFile));
        mAppointments = (List<Appointment>) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();

        if(mAppointments != null && !mAppointments.isEmpty()){
            mListOfAppointments.clear();
            mListOfAppointments.addAll(mAppointments);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, mAppointments.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(mFile));

        List<Appointment> list = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
        Appointment appointment = new Appointment(Calendar.getInstance(), "The Calendar");
        list.add(appointment);

        oos.writeObject(list);
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code above writes a `List<Appointment>` to the file `MyFile.ser` in `onStop()`. In `onResume()`, it reads that `List` back into memory.

**MAKE SURE** you check, in `onResume()`, that `mAppointments` **IS NOT NULL** because it will be null the first time you open your app (simply because you haven't created "app.ser" yet - you don't crate it til the first `onStop()`). Your list of `listoffappointments` will be empty the first time, but during subsequent app openings, provided the appointment list wasn't null during the first `onStop()`, `onResume()` will find the file and populate the list of appointments appropriately.

Comment: hi justin thank you so much for this so after looking further into my code i have found out that the arraylist is causing a force close when transferring the elements from one to another for example based off your code in your onresume() when u get mAppointments = (List<Appointment>) ois.readObject(); and i assign it to global arraylist that i have assigned at the of my code like Arraylist<Appointment> globalist = new Arraylist<appointment>(); then mAppointments would have all the values but upon calling globallist.addall(mAppointments); i receive a force close

Comment: Can you post the code for all the relevant parts of you class? Maybe any relevant stacktraces?

Comment: Justin Pollard i added more parts of the code please view the onresume() method i have wrote a comment of my problem to be more specific thanks

Comment: Ok, so here's what's happening: The first time you open your Activity,  the file your opening ("app.ser") hasn't been created yet. If you look at Android's Logcat, you should see a FileNotFoundException. Thus, the first time you start the app, myArray will be null. What I suggest is to either 1) check for myArray being null first before adding to your listoffappointments, or 2) initialize myArray to a new ArrayList<appointment> in onResume() or in the variable definition. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: if(myArray.isEmpty() == false)
    {
      listoffappointments.addAll(myArray);
    }

Comment: i literaly just came to the same conclusion right now and came here to post the answer but you got it too LOL post your asnwer and i will accept it as the right answer thank you for your help appreciated

Comment: Hey lilz, already posted! Good luck with the rest of the app!